# How do I draw outside a pasted image in paint.net?

Tags: paint.net

To create snippets for our documentation we generally take small pictures using the Windows snipping tool and then put them into Paint.Net to add some text to the image.

The trouble is, if I paste an image into Paint.NET that now becomes the only area where I can add text/shapes/etc.

For instance, if I create a new image that's size 800x600 I can draw anywhere in the image. I think paste in a screenshot of size 400x200. My original drawings are still visible, but I can no longer add anything outside of the 400x200 area of my pasted screenshot. I've tried pasting normally, and pasting as a new layer, but nothing works. The background layer cannot be edited outside of the 400x200 area after pasting in the image.

Comment: I don't use paint.net but is there a function to change the _canvas size_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you paste a screenshot in Paint.NET, a selection is visible around the edge of the screenshot. The selection indicates that any edits only available in the area of selection. *This even applies to ms paint, photoshop.*

**Solution:**

To draw/write/paint outside of the pasted screenshot, simply deselect by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> or click the menu `Edit -->> Deselect`. Now you will be able to edit outside of the image.